# PHP: Replace more then one Tab (\t) with one Tab

Tags: php, regex

I have an array with sentences. Sometimes words are divided by tabs, sometimes one, sometimes more then one.

What I want is simple, I guess. I want to change the amount of tabs between words to 1 for all words divided by more then one tab.

```
Example, I want to change this:
\t\t This \t\t\t\t\t is \t\t a\t test.
into this:
\t This \t is \t a \t test.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/\t+/", "\t", $string);
```